# Setting up Compiz Fusion on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: graphics, ubuntu-11.10, compiz

I am a fairly new Linux user. I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my computer. Since i do not know much about the kind of applications that are available on Ubuntu i usually surf the web to find them.

While surfing i came across this application called the compiz fusion which many people have rated as one of the best graphics application for Ubuntu. I have downloaded compiz fusion from ubuntu software center and it is visible in my applications section. I can see "Compiz fusion icon" on my launcher but when i click on it nothing happens? How can i start the animations using compiz fusion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This belongs on [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/), not on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal with `CTRL + ALT + T`

First, update and upgrade your system wtih:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Next, install compiz and all the other effects:
`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main`

Then, in you dash (press `<Super>` key), look for `CompizConfig Settings Manager`

You can find and apply effects from CCSM